# How can I mute a selection, or make the selection completely quiet, in Audacity?

Tags: audacity, digital-audio

Some cursory searching turned up results for how to mute a track in Audacity.

I would like to be able to silence a given selection within a track.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Select the section of audio you want to mute.
2. From the Edit menu, choose Remove Special
3. From the sub-menu, choose Silence Audio.

It looks like Ctrl-L is a shortcut, once you've selected the audio to mute.